How to obtain the longitude and latitude coordinates from point data and identify which row in the .csv file that this point belongs in QGIS
Problem
I have a CSV file with two columns containing longitude and latitude in decimal degrees. I have created a point layer and I was surprised to find that some of the points are located on land and in other countries, but I cannot find the coordinates of these points in my .csv file as I've checked the attribute table. I'm studying an oceanic species, so none of the points should be terrestrial (see the diagram).
Therefore, I need to clean up and correct the GPS coordinates in my .csv file to replot them.
Question
Is it possible to visually number the points with the row number (more specifically the survey number - see data frame sample) in the .csv file so I can backcheck the GPS coordinates again?
My .csv file contains a large amount of data. I'm not an expert in GIS analysis.
Image

Sample of my data frame


can you give a sample of your csv file?

Add a new column and calculate its (integer) value to be the row number. You might need to dump the csv into excel (or equivalent) then export back out if you want to use csv.

@Mapperz Thank you for answering this post. I've added a sample of my data frame. I want to label the point data with the survey number in the data frame (the same as the row number), so I can locate these disorderly coordinates in the attribute table and then clean up the coordinates in my .csv file. If these weird coordinates in the attribute table are different to my .csv file then there is something else wrong.

@AliceHobbs, please update the question's title to reflect your actual question.

Looking at your map image, I think you're getting integer degree values coming through.  The row of points going horizontally through Saudi Arabia looks to be Lat - 28° N and there appear to be 3 points in Egypt (including one on Sinai) on the 34° E line.

The original answer below is a bit redundant since the OP edited the question to show they had a "survey_number" field.
Updated answer:
Select the points you want to show (I used the "select features by area" tool and drew a rectangle to select the points) and then open the attribute table and change the "show all features" dropdown to "show selected features" and note the selected "survey_number" values.

Original answer:
Open CSV layer properties, click "Field calculator" to add a new virtual integer field, call it "row" and set its expression to @id

Select the points you want to find and open the attribute table to see what rows they are:


thank you for answering my question. I'm kind of new to QGIS. Would you mind providing step-by-step instructions for selecting the points so the points that are selected are specified as rows in the table? I'm not sure how to show selected features in the attribute table. Many thanks if you can help

@AliceHobbs My answer is a bit redundant since you edited your question to show you had a "survey_number" field. Just select the points you want to show (I used the "select features by area" tool and drew a rectangle to select the points) and then open the attribute table and change the "show all features" dropdown to "show selected features" and note the selected "survey_number" values.

In order to visually number the points with the survey number as requested, you need to activate the labelling of the layer's features:

open the layer's properties dialog window from the layer's contextual menu in the Layers panel
select the Label properties tab
set the "Single labels" labelling method
set the "Survey_Number" field as the label value
if needed, change the display style of the labels as you wish


@AliceHobbs this answer actually answers your question.

If you have a vector layer representing land mass (e.g. the pre-installed World Map: type World to the coordinate field in the status bar and hit ENTER to load), you can run Select by Location with points layer > intersect > World Map to select the points that are terrestrial.
Then create a new field with field calculator for the selected points only, e.g. a boolean field correct_location with 1=terrestrial and 0 all others.


thank you for your answer, I really appreciated your efforts
